# How to position and format length of a table's title [R Markdown, pander package]

Tags: r, markdown, pandoc, pander

I am preparing R Markdown document in the pdf format. In the document    I have a couple of tables. I used ***pander*** package to format    tables. Suppose that I have data frame, DF, that I want to transform    into table in the pdf output. To achieve that in a r code chunk I    changed *panderOptions* for table caption prefix in order to print it    in NON-English language and in the next line I call pander function    with specified caption argument.

Here is relevant part of R Markdown code:

````
---
title: "Let's try!"
author: "Newbie_R"
date: "Monday, December 15, 2014"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r setoptions, echo = F, message=FALSE}
library (knitr)
library (pander)
opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```


```{r DF}
    vm <- 3/2 + 4/2
    jl <- vm
    ik <- 2+4
    sr <- 3 + 4/2
    lb <- 4
    dk <- 3
    zb <- 3
    ss <- 2

    DF <- data.frame (VM = vm,
                       JL = jl,
                       IK = ik,
                       SR = sr,
                       LB = lb,
                       DK = dk,
                       ZB = zb,
                       SS = ss)

```
Try to make a table!!!



```{r panderTable}
    panderOptions("table.caption.prefix", "XXXXXX 1: ")
    pander (DF, caption = "This is a very long table's title that should be printed above the table; Also, I would like format it to match boundaries of a length of the table")
```
````

The output is not the way I would like. I want to:

1. position table's title (caption) above the table
2. format length of table's title in a way that matches length of the table (wrap text within table's boundaries)
3. move table a bit bellow "Try to make a table!!!" text which is not a part of the r code chunk. Note that the "Try to make a table" text is more closer to the table compared to the table's title.

UPDATE1:

[This link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B90n5RdIvP6qZHA5bEFGSDlXWG8/view?usp=sharing) will direct to the original output. Instead to that one, I want [to make something like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B90n5RdIvP6qYTNiWlRseGNKdVU/view?usp=sharing).

UPDATE2:

On [this GitHub web page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FRapporter%2Fpander%2Fissues%2F102&ei=02GPVKTUMKSpyQPT1ILICQ&usg=AFQjCNFOAI-vruJirxqkKZaT4HPk70mGfg&sig2=WiKQn_WGHeDBzRv8rb_uwA&bvm=bv.81828268,d.bGQ&cad=rja), one can find issue regarding option to place title on the top of a table. [@daroczig](https://github.com/daroczig) said that it is not an issue connected with pander. However he suggested how it could be achieved. Where should I put code lines provided below which @daroczig suggested?

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
```

Comment: Not sure but it doesn't look like an option or at least not included in [these examples](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/blob/master/README.md#caption). Have you tried kable from knitr or xtable or another package? Interestingly, when I try `kable(DF, format = 'pandoc', caption = "Table caption")` in the console, the caption is printed above the table, but when I knit the caption is added below. Must be a pandoc thing..

Comment: @rawr thx for suggestions. I tried kable and xtable but without success. I was looking around I found out that pander package has a bunch of options and I was believing there must be some of them that one can do the job...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a `pander` and not even a markdown issue as Pandoc's mardown has a [definite syntax](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#tables) on where to put the caption: it should be placed below the table **in markdown**.

But after transforming markdown to HTML or PDF, you had the freedom to (re)place that caption wherever you wish, as Pandoc converted the markdown table to a regular `table` LaTeX environment, which could be easily customized by the above referenced `floatrow` package.

Unfortunately this is no longer possible, as Pandoc uses `longtable` instead of `table` or `ctable`, where the placement of caption is defined by Pandoc's version: it used to put the caption below the table, but since a [recent commit](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/66378062b622b0815a1a2ddce5d557e3ad13330c), captions are placed above tables. For more details, see the [related thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.pandoc/10277) on Pandoc's maillist.

Comment: thx for clarification. Do have any idea how I can solve problem 2. and 3. from my post (especially 2.)?

Comment: @Newbie_R: Unfortunately `#2` is not an easy one with `longtable`, but e.g. using other LaTeX environment (such as `threeparttable`) supports this setup. But with current version of `pandoc` you are forced to use `longtable`, thus manually specifying the caption width is your last resort: `\captionsetup{width=.75\textwidth}` with the `caption` LaTeX package. About `#3`: that's a rather simple LaTeX question, you might use e.g. `\vspace{10mm}` to have 1cm of white space wherever you place this.