# Put table captions on top when knitting Word .doc with R markdown

Tags: rstudio, knitr, caption, .doc, pander

Table captions are positioned below the table when using R markdown to knit a Word document in RStudio.  I need the table captions above the table.

I have tried the kable() and pander() functions without success.

A solution using xtable() when knitting .pdf can be found here:
[How to make RMarkdown (.Rmd) table captions go at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867689/how-to-make-rmarkdown-rmd-table-captions-go-at-the-top)

However, to my knowledge xtable() is not compatible when knitting to Word .doc.

The capability for this option was downplayed in [How to position and format length of a table's title [R Markdown, pander package]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493079/how-to-position-and-format-length-of-a-tables-title-r-markdown-pander-package/27495000#27495000) due to pandoc policy of table captions on bottom.  My recent visits to the pandoc documentation indicate that this policy has been rescinded.

I would like to continue using R markdown to knit Word documents, but will have to abandon if table captions remain below the table.

Comment: The placement of the caption in the markdown file has no effect on where the caption will be rendered in the resulting `docx` file. It was rendered below the table with `pandoc` and there were no way to change this behavior, but it was updated [recently](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/changelog#L1047) -- so just update `pandoc` to `1.13.2.1+` and keep using (R)markdown :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comment by daroczig, I was able to reach solution by installing the latest version of pandoc using the following commands in R:

```
library(installr)
install.pandoc()
```

Note that reinstalling latest version of RStudio did not update pandoc. This solution works with R 3.2.2; install.pandoc() had an error with R 3.1.3 and installing pandoc manually (ie. from outside R using the msi file) did not fix the problem.